# How to use one way binding with ngClass directive in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of objects. They are displayed with `ngRepeat` direcitve. Each block with information is covered with directive, that has some helper methods.

i.e. it constructs `labelId` variable, that is used in this block with one way binding.

So when I want to display it for example in `for` attribute I have no problem
`{{::label}}`.
When I want to display it as field name, there is also no problem `{{::label}}`.

But when I want to reference it in `ngMessages` block like:

```
<p class="error-message" ng-messages="FormName[::label + '_' + $index].$error" ng-messages-include="error-messages.html"></p>
```

Or when I want to use it for reference to set css class dynamically like:

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error': (FormName[::label + '_' + $index].$error.someErrorName)}">
```

then I'm getting `Error`

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression at column 21 of the expression [{'has-error': (FormName[::label + '_' + $index].$error
```

Comment: `ng-class="::{'has-error': ...}"`

Comment: What if there are other classes, that don't require one way binding?

Comment: I believe angular only allowed you one :: syntax per expression.

Comment: also I think angular only add one $watch for a ng-class, no matter how many classes inside.

Comment: So in other words. Either `ngClass` with all it content is used with one way binding or it is not. If so, then sadlly it is not very flexible in that matter. And what about `ngMessages` block? I'm betting same error there as well.

Comment: not very IE friendly but you can use `class="{{expr1 ? 'has-error' : ''}} {{expr2 ? 'may-be-error' : ''}}"`, not sure that interpolation works with ng-class

Comment: `ng-messages="::FormName ..` not working? then no idea. I never use that before.

Comment: It didn't work with `ngClass`, nor with `ngMessages` in my case. After removing `::` in both places it worked great. Sadlly this way I'm getting unwanted watchers as far as I understand.

Comment: yes, two `{{ ... }}` generate two watchers, so may be ng-class without one-way binding may be better after all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89366/discussion-between-eugene-and-you).

Comment: I can't type in chat. if you have partial two-way binding in ng-class, yes not much choice there as far as I know.

Comment: @YOU could you maybe form your comment as an answer, since it did help, so that this question could be closed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ng-class has one way binding syntax too

```
ng-class="::{'has-error': ..., 'no-error': ...}"
```

But it is one expression even if there is many classes inside.

So if you need two-way binding for some classes inside that ng-class, then one way binding cannot be used.